# Swift Pattern Matching - multiple enum-case-pattern in guard?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, guard-statement

What's the correct syntax for using enum cases and guard to allow more-than-one case to proceed?

With a `switch` we can use a [case-item-list](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_case-item-list) to combine switch cases.

Is there anything like that for `guard` or `if` statements?

Here's a code example of kinda-sorta what I'd like to do...

```
enum Thingy {
    case one
    case two
    case three
}

func doSomething(with value: Thingy) {
    switch value {
    case .one, .three:
        print("I like these numbers")
    default:
        print("Two")
    }
}

// Doesn't compile
func doSomethingAlt(with value: Thingy) {
    guard .one, .three = value else {
        print("Two")
        return
    }

    print("I like these numbers")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give the conditions separated by an `OR` (`||`) condition. Here is how:

```swift
func doSomethingAlt(with value: Thingy) {
    guard value == .one || value == .three else {
        print("Two")
        return
    }

    print("I like these numbers")
}
```

This would require for the `enum` to conform to `Equatable`. `Enums` without associated values or with `raw-type` automatically conform to `Equatable`. Since `Swift 4.1` enum cases even with associated-types automatically conform to `Equatable`. Here is some code:

```swift
enum Thingy: Equatable {
    case one(String)
    case two
    case three
}
func doSomethingAlt(with value: Thingy) {
    guard value == .one("") || value == .three else {
        print("Two")
        return
    }

    print("I like these numbers")
}
```

And, since `Swift 5.1` enum associated type can have default values. Which is an awesome feature so you just need to do this:

```swift
enum Thingy: Equatable {
    case one(String = "")
    case two
    case three
}
func doSomethingAlt(with value: Thingy) {
    guard value == .one() || value == .three else {
        print("Two")
        return
    }

    print("I like these numbers")
}
```

Comment: This requires that `Thingy` conform to `Equatable,` which is no problem for my toy example.

Comment: @edelaney05 That's true! Otherwise, you could use the `switch` condition, which would be the right method to handle `enums`.

Comment: @edelaney05 I've updated my answer and added the fact about equatable conformance. Thanks.